# Performance testing with RSpec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to incorporate performance tests into a test suite for *non-Rails* app and have a couple problems.

1. I don't need to run perf tests every time, how can I exclude them? Commenting and uncommenting `config.filter_run_excluding :perf => true` seems like a bad idea.
2. How do I report benchmark results? I think RSpec has some mechanism for that.

Answer (score 4):

I created [rspec-benchmark](https://github.com/piotrmurach/rspec-benchmark) Ruby gem for writing performance tests in RSpec. It has many expectations for testing speed, resources usage, and scalability.

For example, to test how fast your code is:

```
expect { ... }.to perform_under(60).ms
```

Or to compare with another implementation:

```
expect { ... }.to perform_faster_than { ... }.at_least(5).times
```

Or to test computational complexity:

```
expect { ... }.to perform_logarithmic.in_range(8, 100_000)
```

Or to see how many objects get allocated:

```
expect {
  _a = [Object.new]
  _b = {Object.new => 'foo'}
}.to perform_allocation({Array => 1, Object => 2}).objects
```

To filter your tests you can separate the specs into a `performance` directory and add a rake task

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

desc 'Run performance specs'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:perf) do |task|
  task.pattern = 'spec/performance{,/*/**}/*_spec.rb'
end
```

Then run them whenever you need them:

```
rake perf
```

Answer (score 2):

First problem partially solved and second problem solved completely with this piece of code in `spec/spec_helper.rb`

```
class MessageHelper
  class << self
    def messages
      @messages ||= []
    end

    def add(msg)
      messages << msg
    end
  end
end

def message(msg)
  MessageHelper.add msg
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_excluding :perf => !ENV["PERF"]

  c.after(:suite) do
    puts "\nMessages:"
    MessageHelper.messages.each {|m| puts m}
  end
end
```